# How to define goals at GA4 (new version)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have created new account at google analytics
and discovered that it has new UI: there is no View,no way to add goals. How to add it ?

[image: there is no VIEW]

Answer (score 2):

Just **switch on** the toggle of an **event** in Conversion report to mark it as **conversion**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By turning on conversions you still cant create page-based goals in GA4 like it was in UA.
But there is a workaround to create old-style goals in GA4. Try out this hack https://youtu.be/FIACPMGcTkg